# Use inline script in views yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I found a jquery code online to integrate google map and i want to integrate in my application to get the address correctly.
[This is the jquery i found](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker). I am using yii2 Advanced template. I created a new AssetBundle named LocateAsset.php code is as follows

```
class LocateAsset extends AssetBundle
{
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
];
public $js = [
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js',
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js',
    'src/jquery.ui.addresspicker.js',
    'src/addresspickermap.js',

];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
}
```

There was inline scripting on original demo plugin page but i created separate .js file named addresspickermap.js.
I did register the form using

```
use backend\assets\LocateAsset;
LocateAsset::register($this);
```

And in the same _form.php i used the code to integrate map

```
<div class="event-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
 <?= $form->field($model, 'location')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<div class='clearfix'>
<div class='input input-positioned'>
  <label>Address : </label> <input id="addresspicker_map" />   <br/>
  <label>Locality: </label> <input id="locality" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>SubLocality: </label> <input id="sublocality" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>Borough: </label> <input id="administrative_area_level_3" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>District: </label> <input id="administrative_area_level_2" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>State/Province: </label> <input id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>Country:  </label> <input id="country" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>Postal Code: </label> <input id="postal_code" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>Lat:      </label> <input id="lat" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>Lng:      </label> <input id="lng" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>Zoom:     </label> <input id="zoom" disabled=disabled> <br/>
  <label>Type:     </label> <input id="type" disabled=disabled /> <br/>
</div>

<div class='map-wrapper'>
  <label id="geo_label" for="reverseGeocode">Reverse Geocode after Marker Drag?</label>
  <select id="reverseGeocode">
    <option value="false" selected>No</option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
  </select><br/>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="legend">You can drag and drop the marker to the correct location</div>
</div>
```

```
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>


</div>
```

But i dont know what i am missing on my form page that i am not getting the map on the form page
Neither the address field works
Let me know what am i doing wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Try this, for register JS file use `$this->registerJsFile('pathoffile');` and for register JS Script use `$this->registerJs('js script');`

Comment: @gamitg tried that as well.. not working.. i tried simple input of adding map using `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>` this script its working but that plugin uses some different map AJAX map. May be that is the reason its not loading on the page

Comment: Where are your files located physically? At first glance it will look in `frontend/web/src`, is that where they are? Also: Check your browser console for files that can't be loaded and add those to your question please.

Comment: @Blizz My files are located under backend/web/src and i can see from the page source from browser that all those external script are getting loaded. As far as i know the main problem is with the http:/Ajax link because i tried posting the map only on the page and it works but when i insert the Ajax link of google map thats when it stops working

Comment: @Blizz i have narrow down the problem to jquery error. When i used the browser debugger it dispalys GET error of the javascript. It works fine without yii2 framework but having error with yii2. Any idea what is the reason of this conflict??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. If you want to check weather the script is working or not than try `firebug` or in google chrome,go to inspect element on that page,go to source section and locate the script there.

Use breakpoints and refresh the page or generate the event which should use the script and you will know that your script is included or not.

There might be one more issue that your `css` code might be conflicting with same name. Try changing the name or id of the map and see.

Google examples of integrating maps and you will find tons of example on how to implement the map on your page.

Comment: thank you.. its actually been resolved before but i am accepting your answer because the problem was with `css` i was using and i also used one of the script to achieve this rather than reinventing wheel